# Python: How do I output a element to a specific column and rows depending on the result of if statement

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Incorporating with excel, I'm looking for a solution that would copy a specific element to another element depending if isOrganization is true. Using pandas df['isOrganization'] = df['Code'].str.endswith('000') statement, I managed to list true and false result with print function.

If the column isOrganization is true, then the row that is true should be copied from column E and F to column B and C. Else: the row should be copied from column E and F to column D and E

I.E. : This copies the entire column # dfo[['B', 'C']] = df[['E', 'F']] but I would only like to copy single row from the column.

Attempt:

```
dfo = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel('input.xls')

df['ifOrganization'] = df['Code'].str.endswith('000')

for idx, val in enumerate(df['ifOrganization']):
    if val == True:
        print(idx, val) #dfo[['B', 'C']] = df[['E', 'F']]
else:
    print(idx, val) #dfo[['D', 'E']] = df[['E', 'F']]
```

This is printed for isOrganization output:

[image: Output]

This is printed for pf(column) output:

[image: Output]

First few element under E and F:

[image: Element under E and F]

Comment: Super, so instead `B,C,D,E` use values from columns names like `Description` or `Tax Types` like you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with set columns by mask, convert mask to column is not necessary. Also for match False values is used `~` for inverting mask:

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xls')

mask = df['Code'].str.endswith('000', na=False)

df.loc[mask, ['B', 'C']] = df.loc[mask,['F', 'G']].to_numpy()

df.loc[~mask, ['D', 'E']] = df.loc[~mask, ['F', 'G']].to_numpy()

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Code':['code000','code001','code002'] * 2,
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':[7,8] * 3,
         'G':[1,0] * 3
})
```

If test columns names:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['Code', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
mask = df['Code'].str.endswith('000', na=False)

df.loc[mask, ['B', 'C']] = df.loc[mask,['F', 'G']].to_numpy()

df.loc[~mask, ['D', 'E']] = df.loc[~mask, ['F', 'G']].to_numpy()

print (df)
      Code  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  code000  7  1  1  5  7  1
1  code001  5  8  8  0  8  0
2  code002  4  9  7  1  7  1
3  code000  8  0  7  9  8  0
4  code001  5  2  7  1  7  1
5  code002  4  3  8  0  8  0
```

Comment: @Joe - Heading? What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @Joe - `B,C,D` are columns names? Added sample data for see it, how working with some sample data, also solution was changed, bcause was incomplete.

Comment: Yes F and G s are names in Strings and Unicode.

Comment: @Joe - yes, but what is `df = pd.read_excel('input.xls')` and then `print (df.columns)` ? Because error menas there is no column `F` or `G` or both. Excel columns `A,B,C,D...` are not same like pandas columns.

Comment: @Joe - yes, then change `F` to `Corporate Name`, `G` to `Initiaton Date`. Pandas columns are not same like excel columns `A,B,C, D...`.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you kindly for elaborating it clearly. I was a bit slow in understanding your previous comment.

Comment: @Joe - Dont worry, if starting with pandas there is huge information, so not easy for you. Later it will be better and better ;) Happy coding!

Comment: I'm having error code: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. 
After attempt with changing mask to mask = df['Code'].str.endswith('000') == True:: a new error code:shape mismatch: value array of shape (487,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (0,2)

Comment: @Joe - There is parameter `na` so use `mask = df['Code'].str.endswith('000', na=False)` for convert missing values to `False` in mask

Comment: It worked! It is the kind of people like you that makes this community wonderful! Thank you for your encouragement as well! @jezrael

Comment: @Joe - You are welcome, especially if help you with same name like me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Code'].str.endswith('000'),['B','C']] = df[['F','G']]
```

And for the other add `~` to negate condition

Comment: Tested and solution is bad, it create NaNs.