# Python: How do I output a element to a specific column depending on the result of a sequence of condition statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Incorporating excel and pandas, I'm looking for a solution that would distinguish a specific industry number and copy the element under the corresponding column by row.

I.E. : When the industrial code is 58, the Archival date should be copied under the column 58 on the same row.

With the help of [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087895/python-how-do-i-output-a-element-to-a-specific-column-and-rows-depending-on-the), I was able to create the first condition of whether if the company code ends with 000 or not.

Attempt:

```
mask = df['Code'].str.endswith('000') == True
mask21 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('21') == True
mask57 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('57') == True
mask58 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('58') == True
mask59 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('59') == True
mask70 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('70') == True
mask71 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('71') == True
mask74 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('74') == True
mask75 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('75') == True
maskA008 = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith('A008') == True

df.loc[mask, ['c1','c2']] = df.loc[mask,['Code','Corporate Name']].to_numpy()
df.loc[~mask, ['c3','c4']] = df.loc[~mask, ['Code','Corporate Name']].to_numpy()

df.loc[mask21, ['c21']] = df.loc[~mask21, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask57, ['c57']] = df.loc[~mask57, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask58, ['c58']] = df.loc[~mask58, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask59, ['c59']] = df.loc[~mask59, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask70, ['c70']] = df.loc[~mask70, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask71, ['c71']] = df.loc[~mask71, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask74, ['c74']] = df.loc[~mas`enter code here`k74, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[mask75, ['c75']] = df.loc[~mask75, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
df.loc[maskA008, ['A008']] = df.loc[~maskA008, ['End Date']].to_numpy()
```

Error code: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

---

Comment: Please don't post images. Paste everything as text.

Comment: My apologies, updated question with better legibility. My code is enclosed with ``` code format, I don't believe the code itself is a picture.

Comment: I think you need check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new columns by dictionary with values for matching of end of strings in keys of dictionary and new columns names in values in dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Industry Code":['a0021','b400557','aa', 'aa009359'],
                   "End Date":['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03', '2015-01-04']})


ends = {'21':'c21','57':'c57','59':'c59','A008':'A008'}

for k, v in ends.items():
    mask = df['Industry Code'].str.endswith(k, na=False)
    df.loc[mask, v] = df.loc[mask, 'End Date']
    #if need append inverse mask
    #df.loc[mask, v] = df.loc[~mask, 'End Date']

print (df)
  Industry Code    End Date         c21         c57         c59 A008
0         a0021  2015-01-01  2015-01-01         NaN         NaN  NaN
1       b400557  2015-01-02         NaN  2015-01-02         NaN  NaN
2            aa  2015-01-03         NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
3      aa009359  2015-01-04         NaN         NaN  2015-01-04  NaN
```

Comment: @Joe - like python ;)